# Problemas con GIF y PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, php8

a todos!

Me encuentro con un conflicto: Quiero hacer que al poner una url de un GIF este se guarde en una carpeta predeterminada y que cambie de tamaño pero manteniendo proporciones de la imagen.

Lo demás lo tengo, pero cuando hago que copie la imagen gif a la carpeta, lo hace pero queda como imagen estática y no logro que siga funcionando "*en caso que este tenga movimiento*"

El código que tengo hasta ahora, ya que estaba haciendo pruebas!

```
function saveAvatarGif() {
    global $tsCore, $tsUser;
    # URL de la imagen ejemplo https://c.tenor.com/4pCLnLgCfcoAAAAM/vivaan-lal.gif
    $gif = $tsCore->setSecure($tsCore->parseBadWords($_POST['gif']), true);

    $datos = getimagesize($gif);

    if(!is_dir(TS_FILES . "avatar_gif")) {
        mkdir(TS_FILES . "avatar_gif");
        chmod(TS_FILES . "avatar_gif", 0777);
    }

    $img = imagecreatefromgif($gif);
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 120);
    imagecopyresampled($newImage, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 120, $datos[0], $datos[1]);

    # ejemplo c:/xampp/htdocs/files/avatar_gif/1_120.gif
    imagegif($newImage, TS_FILES . "avatar_gif/" . $tsUser->uid . "_120.gif" );
    imagedestroy($newImage);


    /* una consulta que guardo en la base de datos (no hace falta) */
}
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.

DESDE YA MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Comment: Mejor que te mires lo que dicen aquí como respuesta, no es trivial si quieres hacerlo con PHP directamente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation

Comment: @masterguru okay, lo miraré... Y gracias por responder rápido!